# General purpose paging and summary information

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a query that returns several thousand records and I'm using some paging to make the results present nicely to the user.  In my view, however, I need to have a chart control that displays information of the entire result set, not just what page the user is on at any given time.  I'm thinking of a couple ways to solve this:

Let the controller do it's paging thing and on the initial get from the page fire an AJAX call to fetch the entire query and set the chart's source with that.

Or add the entire JSON response as a property to a view model for my view.  and do something like `viewModelChart.JsonResponse = chart.dataSource` kind of thing.  Is there a particular pattern to follow when doing something like this?  Any horror stories down the road to be aware of if I choose one path or the other?

Comment: They're both fine, though if you don't need to do live updates on the chart, I'd lean towards the ViewModel so it is your one-stop shop for all the data your view requires.

Comment: That's where I was leaning toward, thanks.